# Python Prevent Rounding Error with floats

Tags: python, rounding

I have checked dozens of other questions on stackoverflow about rounding floats in Python. I have learned a lot about how computers store these numbers, which is the root cause of the issue. However, I have not found a solution for my situation.

Imagine the following situation:

```
amount = 0.053
withdraw = 0.00547849

print(amount - withdraw)

>>> 0.047521509999999996
```

Here, I would actually like to receive 0.04752151, so a more rounded version.
However, I do not know the number of decimals these numbers should be rounded upon.

If I knew the number of decimals, I could do the following:

```
num_of_decimals = 8
round((amount - withdraw),num_of_decimals)
>>> 0.04752151
```

However, I do not know this parameter num_of_decimals. It could be 8,5,10,2,..

Any advice?

Comment: You might find success with https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Don't use floats for money.

Comment: Use Decimal: `from decimal import Decimal; amount = Decimal(0.053)`

Comment: if you know how floats are stored, you know that's not the correct thing to store the information you want to store

Comment: "However, I do not know the number of decimals these numbers should be rounded upon." Well, it is **not possible** to determine this simply by looking at the value. `floats` **do not have** "decimal digits". Please make sure to distinguish things from *representations of* things. And think carefully: **where did the numbers come from**? If you typed them into your program, then you should be able to decide on the precision when you are typing them in. If you got them by reading a text file, then look **at the text, before** doing any numeric conversion. Etc.

Comment: But as is, the question cannot be *properly* answered without that sort of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concentrating purely on the number of decimal places, something simple, like converting the number to a string might help.

```
>>> x = 0.00547849
>>> len(str(x).split('.')[1])
8
>>> x = 103.323
>>> len(str(x).split('.')[1])
3
```

It appears that I've offended the gods by offering a dirty but practical solution but here goes nothing, digging myself deeper.

If the number drops into scientific notation via the str function you won't get an accurate answer.
Picking the bones out of '23456e-05' isn't simple.
Sadly, the decimal solution also falls at this hurdle, once the number becomes small enough e.g.

```
>>> withdraw = decimal.Decimal('0.000000123456')
>>> withdraw
Decimal('1.23456E-7')
```

Also it's not clear how you'd go about getting the string for input into the decimal function, because if you pump in a float, the result can be bonkers, not to put too fine a point on it.

```
>>> withdraw = decimal.Decimal(0.000000123456)
>>> withdraw
Decimal('1.23455999999999990576323642514633416311653490993194282054901123046875E-7')
```

Perhaps I'm just displaying my ignorance.

So roll the dice, as to your preferred solution, being aware of the caveats.
**It's a bit of a minefield.**

Last attempt at making this even more hacky, whilst covering the bases, with a default mantissa length, in case it all goes horribly wrong:

```
>>> def mantissa(n):
...     res_type = "Ok"
...     try:
...         x = str(n).split('.')[1]
...         if x.isnumeric():
...             res = len(x)
...         else:
...             res_type = "Scientific notation "+x
...             res = 4
...     except Exception as e:
...         res_type = "Scientific notation "+str(n)
...         res = 4
...     return res, res_type
... 
>>> print(mantissa(0.11))
(2, 'Ok')
>>> print(mantissa(0.0001))
(4, 'Ok')
>>> print(mantissa(0.0001234567890))
(12, 'Ok')
>>> print(mantissa(0.0001234567890123456789))
(20, 'Ok')
>>> print(mantissa(0.00001))
(4, 'Scientific notation 1e-05')
>>> print(mantissa(0.0000123456789))
(4, 'Scientific notation 23456789e-05')
>>> print(mantissa(0.0010123456789))
(13, 'Ok')
```

Comment: OP specifically said "I do not know this parameter num_of_decimals", otherwise they would use the built-in `round` rather than using strings for that purpose

Comment: hey this indeed works! It is kind of a different approach but I tried it with a few examples and it does the trick!

Comment: @njzk2 I think you've got the wrong end of the stick. This answer specifically addresses the 'I dont know how many decimals there are' part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, but if I have that piece of information I can round the float on that, giving me the correct answer.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony indeed, sorry. But you still have the wrong end of the stick and your solution is an ugly hack: the issue is not the number of decimals, it's the fact that floats are not accurate

Comment: Note that this gives subtly wrong results in cases like `x = 0.0000123456`. In that case there are ten digits following the decimal point, but `len(str(x).split(".")[1])` gives `9`. And for `x = 0.00001` we get an `IndexError`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Indeed, scientific notation can be a killer. I suppose that a check could be made for a numeric result. If it's not numeric choose an arbitrary number of digits but then as I added, it's a bit of a minefield.

Comment: "Also it's not clear how you'd go about getting the string for input into the decimal function". True. using strings as input for decimal is only an option if you have the actual, precise, number. if you have `v = 0.1`, you've already lost.

Comment: "Sadly, the decimal solution also falls at this hurdle, once the number becomes small enough". No. Only the default representation may look confusing because it is displayed in exponent notation. `'{0:f}'.format(withdraw)` gives you the full representation will all the correct zeros.

Answer (score 2):

When decimals are important, then Python offers a `decimal` module that works best with correct rounding.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

amount = Decimal(0.053)
withdraw = Decimal(0.00547849)

print(amount - withdraw)

# 0.04752150999999999857886789911

num_of_decimals = 8
print(round(amount - withdraw,num_of_decimals))
# 0.04752151
```

## Update: Get number of decimal

```
num_of_decimals = (amount - withdraw).as_tuple().exponent * -1

#or find
num_of_decimals = str(amount - withdraw)[::-1].find('.')
```

Instead of `round`

```
from decimal import getcontext

...

getcontext().prec = num_of_decimals

print(amount - withdraw)
# 0.047521510
```

See more [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) documentation

Comment: Hi, I will take a look at the decimal module. But, the problems still remains, how do I know the num_of_decimals value. Because I do not know that up front, all the numbers in my data could have different lenghts. Some could be 0.01233333334 or 0.0120001, etc.

Comment: just use `Decimal` with string input, to have exact value, skipping floats entirely

Comment: Let me rephrase it a bit. This num_of_decimals is just for explanation purposes, it is not something I know. So in the data i have, i only have a list of the amounts and withdraws, where each of them have different number of decimals. So I have to round the amount-withdraw to a decimal number n, which is unknown. But i think that the answer of @rolf_of_saxony works!

Comment: Updated to get decimal len

Answer (score 2):

Use decimal with string inputs:

```
from decimal import Decimal

amount = Decimal("0.053")
withdraw = Decimal("0.00547849")

print(amount - withdraw)

# 0.04752151
```

Avoid creating floats entirely, and avoid the rounding issues.

If you end up with numbers small enough, and the default representation is now something like `1.2345765645033E-8`, you can always get back to decimal notation in your representation:

```
>>> withdraw = Decimal("0.000000012345765645033")
>>> '{0:f}'.format(withdraw)
'0.000000012345765645033'
```